# Why does the bullet not go perfectly towards the cursors position?

Tags: java, game-development

The bullets doesnt go pefectly towards the cursor and is usually a few degrees off, but when I multiply the velocity by like 20 it does.

```
this.bulletSpeed = bulletSpeed;
double angle = Math.atan2(cursorY - shipYCenter, cursorX - shipXCenter);

vx = (int) (bulletSpeed * Math.cos(angle));
vy = (int) (bulletSpeed * Math.sin(angle));
```

[Sample of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqf3F.png)

I've tried multiple formulas and the result is all the same, I tried turning the velocities into doubles but the result is stayed the same maybe I did it wrong but now I'm not sure what to do next. I've also tried a lot of the solutions here but I haven't found one specific to my problem

Comment: Maybe because you cast to `int` for some reason!?

Comment: When you turned vx and vy into doubles (IMO absolutely necessary to avoid rounding errors), did you maybe forgot to remove the (int) casts?

Comment: I casted it to int because my x and y are also int, does it make any difference if I casted them to int right before I add them to the x and y values?

Comment: You have to keep X and y as double values as well, only convert to int when drawing to the screen or so. This way, you can add up the fractional parts correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are converting the real values to ints, you are building up a trajectory error.  Note that converting the vx and vy to floats probably won't fix this unless you recompute the trajectory for each iteration/frame.

Comment: then what can i do? I can recompute the velocity every frame but if there's any easier way to do it I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 0):

All the variables vx, vy, x and y should be of type `double`. Only when you e.g. call the drawing method of Graphics2d, you need to cast x and y to `int`. This way, the rounding errors don't add up in each iteration.